# UIAlertController crashes app when presented from NSURLSessionDataTask?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, jailbreak, cydia

Why does this not work?

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    NSString *receivedDataString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    NSString *keyInfo = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:keyString] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"%@", receivedDataString);
    NSLog(@"%@", keyInfo);

    if (![receivedDataString isEqual:keyInfo] && ![receivedDataString isEqual: @""])
    {
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        UIAlertController *alertCheckForUpdate;

        UIAlertAction *noUpdateBtn = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];
        UIAlertAction *yesCydiaUpdateBtn = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cydia" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"cydia://sources"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
        }];
        UIAlertAction *yesSileoUpdateBtn = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Sileo" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"sileo://package/com.dave1482.powerapp"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
        }];

        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:sileoPath] && ![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:cydiaPath]){
            alertCheckForUpdate = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"New Update Available" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Open Sileo to update PowerApp to v%@?", receivedDataString] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            [alertCheckForUpdate addAction:yesSileoUpdateBtn];
        } else if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:sileoPath] && [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:cydiaPath]) {
            alertCheckForUpdate = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"New Update Available" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Open Cydia to update PowerApp to v%@?", receivedDataString] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            [alertCheckForUpdate addAction:yesCydiaUpdateBtn];
        } else if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:sileoPath] && [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:cydiaPath]) {
            alertCheckForUpdate = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"New Update Available" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Open Cydia/Sileo to update PowerApp to v%@?", receivedDataString] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            [alertCheckForUpdate addAction:yesCydiaUpdateBtn];
            [alertCheckForUpdate addAction:yesSileoUpdateBtn];
        } else {
            alertCheckForUpdate = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"New Update Available" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PowerApp v%@ is available but for some reason you don't have Sileo or Cydia.", receivedDataString] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        }
        [alertCheckForUpdate addAction:noUpdateBtn];
        [self presentViewController:alertCheckForUpdate animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

The following line crashes my app, it seems attempting to present my UIAlertController inside the block caused this. I am using the latest Xcode and SDK while targeting iOS 8+. Thank you!

```
[self presentViewController:alertCheckForUpdate animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Full file is here: https://github.com/Dave1482/PowerApp/blob/master/PowerApp/ViewController.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the error message you're getting upon crashing? My guess is you're trying to present the alert from a background thread in which case you'll need to present it like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentViewController:alertCheckForUpdate animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Comment: Thank you! You are correct, it was run in the background! This fixed it perfectly. If you want, I can add credit to you for your help.